# cvCreateButton VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, opencv

When I use the code

```
cvCreateButton("button1",callbackButton2,NULL,CV_PUSH_BUTTON,1);

void callbackButton2(int state, void *pointer){

    int i = 2;

    return;
}
```

I get the following error in visual studios 2010 
error C2065: 'callbackButton2' : undeclared identifier

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong to cause this error

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code presented it appears that `callbackButton2` is used on the first line but is declared after this on the second line.

In most languages this is not a legal thing to do because an identifier is not valid until the compiler can determine the context(s) in which it can be used which is what declaring an identifier does

Try this:

```
    void callbackButton2(int state, void *pointer){

    int i = 2;

    return;
}

cvCreateButton("button1",callbackButton2,NULL,CV_PUSH_BUTTON,1);
```

In that code sample the identifier `callbackButton2`is declared as a function before being used as an argument to the `cvCreateButton` function and should therefore be a valid use of the identifier